# In ReactJs, How to Passing or retrieving state of a component into another such that both components are part of third component to divide the actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There are 3 React components with me,

I have a component say **Details** which decides which of the other two components say **Summary** and **Documents** to be retrieved, given below:

```
import Summary from './Summary'
import Documents from './Documents'

class Details extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      summary: true,
      documents: false
    }
  }
render() {
    return (
 <Summary {...this.state} />
 <Documents {...this.state} />
)}

}
export default Details
```

**Summary** component has some manipulation of states through DB and sets some state as below:

```
class Summary extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
       summaryData: {
        mydata: {
          dataNo: '',
          subTotal: '',
          gst: '',
          gstAmount: '',
          totalAmount: '',
        }        
      },
      agreementDocs: []
    }
   }

componentDidMount() {

    let thisComponent = this
    Axios({
      method: 'get',
       url: http://xyszz/somedata,
      data: {},
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    })
      .then(function(response) {
        thisComponent.setState({
          summaryData: response.data.summaryData,
          agreementDocs: response.data.agreementDocs
        })
      })
      .catch(function(error) {

      })
  }
  }
export default Summary
```

currently below is the code of **Documents** Component where I cannot figure out how to get the updated state of summary component:

```
class Documents extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    console.log(props)
    this.state = {}
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container module-billing-attachments">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-12">Attached documents here</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Documents
```

> The third **Documents** component is the one in which I want the updated
>   state in **Summary** Component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this is one of the situation that might introduce redux for you ... you use redux to keep a global state for all you components and then you connect your component with redux to access the global state.

But lets consider that you don't want to use redux and you just want to use components state.

You can do that by keeping a handler function in `Details` component and pass it as props to `summary` component and whenever the state of summary is updated after the `axios` call you call that handler....

Then you update the state of `details` component with the updates happened in `summary` and finally pass this updated state to `document` component

Check the code below:

Details Component

```
import Summary from './Summary'
import Documents from './Documents'

class Details extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      summary: true,
      documents: false,
      summary: {}
    }

    this.summaryChanged = this.summaryChanged.bind(this);
  }

  summaryChanged(updatedState){
    this.setState({
        summary:updatedState
    })

  }


render() {
    return (
 <Summary {...this.state}  handleChange={this.summaryChanged} />
 <Documents {...this.state}  summaryState={this.state.summary} />
)}

}
export default Details
```

Summary component

```
class Summary extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
       summaryData: {
        mydata: {
          dataNo: '',
          subTotal: '',
          gst: '',
          gstAmount: '',
          totalAmount: '',
        }        
      },
      agreementDocs: []
    }
   }

componentDidMount() {

    let thisComponent = this
    Axios({
      method: 'get',
       url: http://xyszz/somedata,
      data: {},
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    })
      .then(function(response) {
        thisComponent.setState({
          summaryData: response.data.summaryData,
          agreementDocs: response.data.agreementDocs
        } , ()=> {
            this.props.handleChange(this.state);
        })
      })
      .catch(function(error) {

      })
  }
  }
export default Summary
```

Finally Document component

````
class Documents extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    console.log(props)
    this.state = {
        summaryState : {}
    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.setState({
        summaryState : this.props.summaryState
    })
    //now you have all the updated state of summary component as ```this.state.summaryState```
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container module-billing-attachments">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-12">Attached documents here</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Documents
````

Comment: There I understood the use of Redux, Thank you for that, but I would like to deep dive into second option, can you please elaborate on that about, Handler in details and passing the props to summary??

Answer (score 2):

Redux seems like overkill here, your component tree is still straightforward.

You want to move your state higher into the application using callbacks.  Define a method on `<Details>` which accepts a response from Axios, then pass that function as a prop down to `<Summary>`.  Keep the `summaryData` and `agreementDocs` in `<Summary>`, then pass them down as props to `<Documents>`.

Something like...

```
class Details extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.saveSummary = this.saveSummary.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            summary: true,
            documents: false,
            summaryData : null,
            agreementDocs : []
        }
    }

    saveSummary(res){
        this.setState({
            summaryData : res.summaryData,
            agreemeentDocs : res.agreementDocs
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Summary {...this.state} saveSummary={this.saveSummary} />
                <Documents {...this.state} />
            </div>
        )}

}
```

Where you then call `this.props.saveSummary` within `<Summary>`.  Also note that a React component can only return one child (unless you're using the brand-spanking new version of React, and so are all your dependencies), so I added a `<div>` in there.